# How to skip DAG when condition does not meet and jump next one in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to check one python function if function result meets condition then move next dag, if it does not meet condition, then jump to a DAG next after next one. I have check condition dag that for example checks random number, **if it bigger than 5** then jump **wait_for_result** DAG by skipping next **run_beagle_script** DAG. Or else just continue one by one.
**Here is the diagram that I am describing.**
[image]

**imputation.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator

from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

def _training_model():
    return randint(1, 10)

def check_condition_func(ti, **kwargs):
    rand_num = _training_model()
    print('check_condition_func result: ', rand_num)
    if (rand_num > 5):
        return 'wait_for_result'
    else:
        return 'run_beagle_script'

def init_params(**kwargs):
    parsed_dag_input = {
        'file_name': 'Imputation',
        'input_format': 'pdf'
    }
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='value', value=parsed_dag_input)

def run_beagle_script(**kwargs):
    imputed_file_name = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='value')['file_name']
    print('imputed_file_name function received file: ', imputed_file_name)
    run_beagle_json = {
        'result': imputed_file_name + '_Beagle'
    }
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='run_beagle_res', value=run_beagle_json)

def wait_for_result_file(**kwargs):
    wait_for_res_val = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='run_beagle_res')['result']
    print('wait_for_result_file function received value: ', wait_for_res_val)
    wait_for_json = {
        'result': wait_for_res_val + '.pdf'
    }
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='wait_for_res', value=wait_for_json)

def update_status(**kwargs):
    update_status_res_val = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='run_beagle_res')['result']
    print('update_status function received value: ', update_status_res_val)


with DAG("imputation_beagle", start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *", catchup=False) as dag:

        input_parameters = PythonOperator(
            task_id="init",
            python_callable=init_params,
            provide_context=True
        )

        checker = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id="check_condition",
            python_callable=check_condition_func,
            provide_context=True
        )

        run_beagle_script_op = PythonOperator(
            task_id="run_beagle_script",
            python_callable=run_beagle_script,
            provide_context=True
        )

        wait_for_result_file_op = PythonOperator(
            task_id="wait_for_result",
            python_callable=wait_for_result_file,
            provide_context=True
        )

        update_job_status = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id="update_status",
            python_callable=update_status,
            provide_context=True
        )

        # input_parameters >> checker >> run_beagle_script_op >> wait_for_result_file_op >> update_job_status
        input_parameters >> checker
        checker >> run_beagle_script_op
        checker >> wait_for_result_file_op
        wait_for_result_file_op >> update_job_status
```

Dag is running successfully, but It is not skipping next and jump to wait_for_result dag in case number is bigger than 5. How Can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You say bigger than 5 but in your code the condition is `>2`

Comment: @EladKalif yes, typo mistake, fixed it.

Comment: Can you please better explain the scenario. Are you saying that run_beagle_script is always successful? Please describe what happens when the value bigger/smaller than 5. I need to understand if the issue is with the branch or with what happens after the branch.

Comment: If value it less than or equal 5, then run_beagle_script  runs and wait_for_result runs after that. In case value is bigger than 5, then run_beagle_script is skipped and wait_for_result dag is run after check_condition dag. I just need to skip conditionally

Comment: What you describe is consistent with your code. I just miss the part of what you want to achieve? You wrote "but It is not skipping next and jump to wait_for_result dag" what is next? It's not very clear what you really want to get.

Comment: real scenarios is a bit different. I just wrote in a simple manner. In real scenario. Inside check_condition, I need to check a file that I receive and check whether it is empty or not. If empty, so I need to skip run_beagle_script dag and go wait_for_result_file_op. Because inside it is giving an error and nothing to process. So If not empty, then I run run_beagle_script and then wait_for_result_file_op. In the end, I just update status of operation in database.